# Delete Custom Events in Mixpanel

Tags: mixpanel

Me and my teammates created a custom event, which we don't want anymore. Is there a way to delete Custom Events in Mixpanel? To delete regular events, we need to contact mixpanel.

If that is not possible without contacting Mixpanel, is there any way to at least hide it? To hide an event, one can use 'Data Management'. Mixpanel documentation mentions that one cannot hide custom events using this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the Custom Events.

1. Go to Segmentation
2. Select the Custom Event
3. A Pencil will appear near the event name. Click it.
4. Click the trash icon

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Albert's answer still holds true with as couple small caveats!

You can edit Custom events from several reports including Insights, Segmentation and the Funnels builder.

A pencil icon will appear next to the selected custom event.

[Pencil Icon to Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQMn2.png)

Select the pencil icon and the edit menu will result. If deleting from Insights, the trash can icon will appear at the bottom left side of the menu.
[Delete Trash Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb2mT.png)